# mat-icons toggle_on and toggle_off not visible

Tags: angular-material

I have used material icons in my project. All the other icons can be seen on the browser.
But toggle_on and toggle_off cannot be seen.
This is how I wrote them

```
<mat-icon color="accent">toggle_off</mat-icon>
<mat-icon color="primary">toggle_off</mat-icon>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I came across this link https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/780

Comment: that link quite old..not sure if is related since this issue is quite recent..me also face the same issue now